# Redux state is not rendering properly

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

Screen A --> Flatlist --> Card A --> QtyButton Component

Screen B --> Flatlist --> Card B --> QtyButton Component

Screen C --> Flatlist --> Card C --> QtyButton Component

Im passing array in flatlist and product object in card and then quantity from that object in QtyButton Component. Quantity is displayed in between minus and plus button.

And from QtyButton Component I'm updating qty of product object based on id in redux. And in Redux the state updates. I'm not retrieving quantity directly in QtyButton. **But instead getting the quantity this way.

`Flatlist --> card --> QtyButton`**

But I'm facing some weird problems.

Screen A --> Flatlist --> Card A --> QtyButton Component `Qty doesn't update on run time. If it does its very slow and sluggish render`

Screen B --> Flatlist --> Card A --> QtyButton Component `Same Screen A scenario`

Screen C --> Flatlist --> Card A --> QtyButton Component `If products are more than two then quantity starts to render slowly.`

And here Reducer

```
Cart = [];
   
export default (state = Cart, action) => {
  const {type, payload, error} = action;
  switch (type) {

   case ACTION_TYPES.CART:
    let cartItems = [...state.Cart];

    // Check if product already exist in cart

    if (cartItems.some(x => x.product_id === 
        payload.item.product_id)) {
         cartItems.map(item =>
          item.product_id === payload.item.product_id
        ? {...item, quantity: item.quantity + 1}
        : item,
    );
    } else {
     cartItems.push({...payload.item, quantity: 1});
    }
   return {...state, Cart: cartItems};

   case ACTION_TYPES.REMOVE_FROM_CART:
    return {
     ...state,
     Cart: state.Cart.filter(x => x.product_id !== payload.id),
   };

   case ACTION_TYPES.INCREMENT:
    return {
    ...state,
    Cart: state.Cart.map(x =>
      x.product_id === payload.id
        ? {...x, quantity: x.quantity + payload.quantity}
        : x,
    ),
  };

  case ACTION_TYPES.DECREMENT:
     return {
    ...state,
    Cart: state.Cart.map(x =>
            x.product_id === payload.id
              ? {...x, quantity: x.quantity - payload.quantity}
              : x,
          ),
  };

 default:
  return state;
```

}

Comment: I don't see any issues with your reducer (except that it is strongly encouraged to use redux toolkit instead of writing non-mutating reducers by hand). How do you get the values from the store to your components? Do you use selectors and the useSelector hook? Can you show this code?

Comment: @GuillaumeBrunerie I have a products array which has data coming from API. Once the product is added to the cart then QtyButton shows up at the bottom of the card. In QtyButton using `props.item.quantity` to display the quantity of product. And when click on the plus button, calling this `props.onSetDecrement(productItem.product_id, 1);` which is inside  
 
`const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onSetIncrement: (id, quantity) => {
      dispatch(setIncrement(id, quantity));
    },
  }
}`

Comment: Do you use function components? Why don't you use the `useDispatch` and `useSelector`? It's much easier to use than connect and mapDispatchToProps.

Comment: Yes, using functional component. Yes, you are right. I'll shift to new way of doing things. But right now using mapDispatchToProps.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the problem.

I was updating the quantity in the nested component(**QtyButton**) and nowhere in Screen A and Screen B, I was not setting the updated quantity from redux store to API array.

Because initially, I was displaying the quantity from the Api array in Flat list and all the way down to the **QtyButton** component.

Call the api
get data from API in state

After setting the state I needed to set the updated quantity from redux store to API state.
This will check the quantity in redux, and whatever the quantity stored in redux will be set to API array.

```
let cart = props.cart;

  for (let i = 0; i < apiState.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < cart.length; j++) {
      if (apiState[i].id === cart [j].id) {
        apiState[i].quantity = cart [j].quantity;
      }
    }
  }

And then in render function

Flatlist
 data={apiState}
 //remaining flatlist stuff
/>
```

And Now I have the updated quantity.